# Android - Relative_to_Parent Vs. Relative_To_Self

Tags: android, android-layout

When dealing with TranslateAnimations, you can move a particular object from position A to position B. The co-ordinates for these positions can be denoted in Relative_To_Self vs. Relative_To_Parent? These positions are represented in percentages.

What exactly does this mean?

For examples, suppose I have a Relative_Layout whose width is set to Fill_Parent and an ImageView in it whose width is lets say 80pixels.

Here is the definition I am looking at:

```
public TranslateAnimation (int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType, float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue)
```

If I set my fromXType to Relative_to_parent and my from X value as 0.0. Does this mean that my imageView will start at the extreme left of the screen?

If I set it to Relative to Parent and fromXValue as -1.0.Does this mean that it will start from -80 pixels from where it is originally?

Are my assumptions correct? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: any correct answers for this already?

Answer (score 0):

```
TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
```

In that case;

Relative to parent (`RELATIVE_TO_PARENT`)

```
0.0f = ParentView.getLeft() value.
1.0f = ParentView.getRight() value.
```

Relative to self (`RELATIVE_TO_SELF`)

```
0.0f = SelfView.getLeft() value.
1.0f = SelfView.getRight() value.
```

For example

```
if parentView.getLeft() = 0, parentView.getRight() = 1000(px), self.getLeft() = 0, self.getRight = 100(px)
```

`RELATIVE_TO_PARENT -> View` will translate from 1000 to 0,

`RELATIVE_TO_SELF -> View` will translate from 100 to 0

Answer (score -1):

Well, here's what the docs say for [RELATIVE_TO_PARENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_PARENT) and [RELATIVE_TO_SELF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_SELF):

```
public static final int RELATIVE_TO_PARENT
```

The specified dimension holds a float and should be multiplied by the height or width of the parent of the object being animated.

```
public static final int RELATIVE_TO_SELF
```

> The specified dimension holds a float and should be multiplied by the height or width of the object being animated.

Seems pretty clear to me.